# how to check a variable string with two values in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

how to check a variable string with two values in terraform.

I want to check a string in a variable with two string values something like the below code.

```
virtual_network_type = var.vnet_type == "External" || "Internal" ? var.vnet_type : null
```

But terraform throws below error message

```
Error: Invalid operand
│ 
│   on ../../modules/test/test-instance.tf line 51, in resource "azurerm_api_management" "apim_demo":
│   51:  virtual_network_type = var.vnet_type == "External" || "Internal" ? var.vnet_type : null
│ 
│ Unsuitable value for right operand: a bool is required.
╵
```

Can we do this in terraform?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A construct like `var.vnet_type == "External" || "Internal"` is something that few languages will accept, really.

```hcl
var.vnet_type == "External" || var.vnet_type == "Internal"
```

On the other hand, is something that will give you a better result.

---

Another solution for those kind of use cases, if you don't want to repeat the variable name is to construct a list of the acceptable values and evaluate if the variable is contained in the list.

Something like:

```hcl
contains(["External", "Internal"], var.vnet_type)
```

---

So,

- either

  ```hcl
  virtual_network_type = var.vnet_type == "External" || var.vnet_type ==  "Internal" ? var.vnet_type : null
  ```
- or

  ```hcl
  virtual_network_type = contains(["External", "Internal"], var.vnet_type) ? var.vnet_type : null
  ```